# Mimicking objects in javascript - design decision

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I seem to often be making the decision to create objects in javascript that are basically the ModelView or Model objects in an MVC architecture. So when the user changes their properties or whatever via the webpage, the javascript object's properties are changed, and then the javascript object is submitted to the controller. The main reasons I am using this approach are:

- Increased flexibility of display.
  Alternatively, everything is done
  with forms so that I can easily post
  them back to the controller. Forms do
  not allow various display options
  such as wrapping around other
  elements and so on.
- I am using a lot of javascript
  anyway. I have to manipulate the
  elements whenever buttons are pressed
  (like swapping two list elements
  around). I also usually hijack the
  buttons and use them with ajax.
- The default model binder rarely works
  on complex objects so I need to
  maintain two sets of objects anyway.
- It is easier to perform complex
  validation on a javascript object
  compared to html.

Are there any libraries or techniques or approach that assist with this approach? Maybe JSON.NET? Do any people try to avoid this approach?

Comment: I would use `nodejs` if you attempting to interface something like this.  It would allow you to write one set of logic/validation and model/view set up for client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken this approach myself but there are some frameworks that sound similar to what you are proposing. The one that looks most interesting is [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/).  It provides data binding to your model among other features.